# Workout suggestions

Tags: weight-loss

Height 5' 2". Weight 96 KGS. Taking medicines for hypothyroidism for 13 years. I want to loose fat and improve my stamina. Suggest me workouts cardio or weight training? Is it possible to reduce weight with hypothyroidism?

Comment: I am presently doing brisk walk of 30 mins. Weekly thrice i am doing a combination of cardio and weights by looking at fitness blender videos. No specific diet i am following right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goals are losing fat and improving stamina. Let's break each one down.

To lose fat, you must be in a caloric deficit (burn more calories than you eat). The usual way to this would be to ballpark your resting metabolic rate (RMR) and consume 500/600 calories less than this and see if you make progress, and adjust accordingly. You would want to eat the majority of your carbohydrates around your workouts so you're less likely to store them as glycogen and eventually fat, to make this fat loss process easier. You'd also want to consume at least a gram of protein per lbs of bodyweight in order to minimize muscle loss, so that your metabolism doesn't go down even further. It is a myth that it is the workout itself that does the fat burning, that's not true. It's the caloric deficit. The workout just helps increase metabolism via muscle mass and activity levels. HOWEVER, you say you have hypothyroidism, so your metabolism isn't like the general public. I don't know the extent of this in your case, but if it is VERY noticeable and is affecting you, then talk to your doctor about some medicines that can help with this. While very dangerous, talk to your doctor about Clenbuterol and Cytomel T3, both have the potential to increase your metabolism but are very dangerous if not used properly so MAKE SURE you talk to a doctor. If it is not that bad, the easiest and most effective way to increase your metabolism would be to increase muscle mass. Start weight training at least 3x a week with proper sleep and lots of food to add 5-15 lbs of muscle to kickstart your metabolism, you can lose the fat later when your metabolism is normal. So for fat loss, just experiment with a few calorie goals, and stick to the one that you make progress with, then decrease over time. It's hard to determine this number since your RMR is affected by your condition. Just experiment.

To improve stamina (going to assume cardiovascular), you need to just work on it. There's no secret to this, if you want to get better at something, you just do it, do it often, do it well, and do it again. One key to this however that most people forget, don't get comfortable! If you get comfortable you're no longer making progress and thus aren't "improving" anything. For example, if you can do a 30 min walk right now without problem, either time your walks and try to get a faster time each time, or walk for longer. Your body adapts quickly so always strive to progress. Don't be shy to add in other cardiocascular activities as well, maybe join a recreational sports club, start biking, running, anything you want, it doesn't have to be something you hate, just pick somethings and look to always improve upon it. It is also very well documented that natural bodybuilding is amazing for cardivascular health, so do some more research into working out on your own on the internet and work out with intensity, always trying to beat your previous self.

The key to both of these goals however is just consistency. You won't see any results over night, you need to be patient and just put the work in.

Let me know if you have any other concerns.

Comment: Want to know is it possible to loose fat without loose skin. I am aged 40

Comment: As long as you don't lose weight very rapidly, that won't be a problem.

Comment: I would like to understand the basics of weight training, how to do it correctly as i dont have access to gym. Pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: that's a very large topic on its own, maybe post a question about it. It'll take a while to learn but there's tons of resources on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of weight loss is going to come from nutrition. What are you doing nutrition wise at the moment?

As far as workouts, what you do at first is not as important as you enjoying it, and doing it consistently. Do you have experience with cardio? With weight training?